# $ \varlimsup_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^a}=\varliminf_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^a} $

Tags: limits-and-convergence

$f(x)$ is continuous for $\forall x \geq 0$ and monotonically decrease. $f(0)=0$. $a>0$. Is it true
$$ \varlimsup_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^a}=\varliminf_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^a}  $$
whenever both are finite or infinite?

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: The counterexample to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419539/compare-two-limits-related-to-h%c3%b6lder-condition/419654#419654 works here, too.